# Java EE DependsOn Local EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.1, glassfish-3

I have an EJB Project with a `@Singleton` EJB defined as:

```
@LocalBean
@Singleton 
@Startup
public class DataModelBean implements DataModelBeanLocal {
```

I then have another EJB Project with another EJB:

```
@LocalBean
@Singleton
@Startup 
@EJB(beanInterface=DataModelBeanLocal.class,name="DataModelBeanLocal")
@DependsOn("DataModelBeanLocal")
public class OutboundRouting implements OutboundRoutingLocal {
```

However the `@DependsOn` is not working, I have tried a number of different values for the `@DependsOn` with no success. The server fails to start with:

> Deployment Error for module: Atlas: Exception while deploying the app : java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid DependsOn dependency 'DataModelBeanLocal' for EJB OutboundRouting%%%EOL%%%

I am not sure what I should be doing here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@Singleton
@DependsOn("DataModelBean")
public class OutboundRouting { ... }
```

Comment: @James what error do you get (because this is how you are supposed to use it)

Comment: From eclipse I get a publishing has encountered a problem: cannot deploy Atlas

  Deployment Error for module: Atlas: Exception while deploying the app : java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid DependsOn dependency 'DataModelBean' for EJB OutboundRouting%%%EOL%%%

Comment: Again not an issue when I deploy manually. Will raise another issue.

Comment: You are sure there are no other previous errors such as class not found errors? This happened for me when I forgot to mark new or changed libraries as deployed dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Define a Singleton with a name

```
@Singleton(name = "DataModelBeanLocal ")
@Startup
public class DataModelBean implements DataModelBeanLocal {
```

in your secound singleton you can now define the dependencies

```
@Singleton
@Startup 
@DependsOn("DataModelBeanLocal")
public class OutboundRouting implements OutboundRoutingLocal {
```

In our Projekt it works fine